# Select all the text of a HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

How can i select the whole HTML document using javascript.

I have tried these functions but dint work!!

```
function SelectAll()
        {
            document.body.focus();
            document.body.select();
        }

function SelectAll()
            {

                document.body.select();
            }
```

My whole code is

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function SelectAll()
        {
            document.body.focus();
            document.body.select();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>LaLa, Lala, laLa , lala, lalala, tralala, some other text</div>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="findField" value="lala" size="20" />
    <button onclick="SelectAll();">Find!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Try this  `$('body').select()`

Comment: @AmitAgrawal No, It dint work!

Comment: @user3873909 did you find any of the answers below satisfying your question? If so please select one as your accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Via [Satya-Weblog](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2013/11/javascript-select-all-content-html-element.html):

```
(function() {
    function selectText(element) {
        var doc = document
            , text = element
            , range, selection
        ;
        if (doc.body.createTextRange) { //ms
            range = doc.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(text);
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) { //all others
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = doc.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
    preTags = document.getElementsByTagName('document.body');
    for(var i=0;i<preTags.length;i++) {
        preTags[i].onclick = function() {selectText(this)};
    }
})();
```

Comment: This should work, except since you only have one body tag you don't need the loop, and it should be `document.getElementsByTagName('body')`

Comment: ichanged the function to
function SelectAll()
  {
   var doc = document
            , text = 'body'
            , range, selection
        ;
        if (doc.body.createTextRange) { //ms
            range = doc.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(text);
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) { //all others
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = doc.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
  }
But not working

Comment: Edit:
function SelectAll()
  {
   var doc = document
            , text = "body"
            , range, selection
        ;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) { //ms
   range = doc.body.createTextRange();
   range.moveToElementText(document.getElementsByTagName("body"));
   range.select();
   } else if (window.getSelection) { //all others
      selection = window.getSelection();
            range = doc.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
   }
  }
Not working!!

Answer (score 1):

To select all text inside an element use this simple code. It will highlight the entire element / tag area with yellow colour and select text inside it on single click.

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var range, selection;
event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(event.target);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
};
```

To select all text in the entire document you can modify this code as shown below:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var range, selection;
    var doc = document.body;
    doc.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(doc);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all text on page

```
document.body.innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
(function() {
    function selectText(element) {
        var doc = document
            , text = element
            , range, selection
        ;
        if (doc.body.createTextRange) { //ms
            range = doc.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(text);
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) { //all others
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = doc.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
    preTags = document.getElementsByTagName('document.body');
    for(var i=0;i<preTags.length;i++) {
        preTags[i].onclick = function() {selectText(this)};
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this.

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 $("#t1").select();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danial786zz/2rucp04y/5/)

Answer (score -1):

document.execCommand("selectAll");

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands